# Data Not Showing In Grid Control Asp.net C#, but Coming at DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, grid, controls

I have 5 text boxes and two dropdown List. I will Enter the data in text boxes and after click "Add" button all the data is comg at DataTable in VS2017. I can see the data from Datatable, But not able to see the data in aspx page.
How to bind the data from DataTable to Grid Control So that User can see the Data.

Below is the Code from CS page:

```
            Griddt.Columns.Add("SrlNo", typeof(string));
            Griddt.Columns.Add("GrnNo", typeof(string));
            Griddt.Columns.Add("GrnDate", typeof(string));
            Griddt.Columns.Add("ItemName", typeof(string));
            Griddt.Columns.Add("ItemCode", typeof(string));
            Griddt.Columns.Add("ChallanQty", typeof(string));
            Griddt.Columns.Add("StoreQty", typeof(string));
            Griddt.Columns.Add("ContainerType", typeof(string));
            Griddt.Columns.Add("ActuallQty", typeof(string));
            Griddt.Columns.Add("PcsQty", typeof(string));
            Griddt.Columns.Add("PONo", typeof(string));

            DataRow drGriddtRow = Griddt.NewRow();

            Newdt.Columns.Add("SrlNo", typeof(string));
            Newdt.Columns.Add("GrnNo", typeof(string));
            Newdt.Columns.Add("GrnDate", typeof(string));
            Newdt.Columns.Add("ItemName", typeof(string));
            Newdt.Columns.Add("ItemCode", typeof(string));
            Newdt.Columns.Add("ChallanQty", typeof(string));
            Newdt.Columns.Add("StoreQty", typeof(string));
            Newdt.Columns.Add("ContainerTypeCode", typeof(string));
            Newdt.Columns.Add("ContainerTypeDescription", typeof(string));

            Newdt.Columns.Add("ActuallQty", typeof(string));
            Newdt.Columns.Add("PcsQty", typeof(string));
            Newdt.Columns.Add("PONo", typeof(string));


            DataRow drNewdtRow = Newdt.NewRow();


            if (Session["DtAll"] != null)
            {
                DtAll = (DataTable)(Session["DtAll"]);
                for (int i = 0; i < DtAll.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (DtAll.Rows[i]["ItemCode"].ToString().ToLower() == ddlItemName.SelectedValue.ToString().ToLower())
                    {
                        MsgBox("Duplicated Item!!");
                        return;
                    }
                }

            }


            drNewdtRow["SrlNo"] = "1";

            drNewdtRow["GrnNo"] = txtGrnNo.Text;
            drNewdtRow["GrnDate"] = txtGrnDate.Text;
            drNewdtRow["ItemName"] = ddlItemName.SelectedItem.Text;
            drNewdtRow["ItemCode"] = ddlItemName.SelectedValue.ToString();
            drNewdtRow["ChallanQty"] = Convert.ToDecimal(txtChallanQty.Text);
            if (txtStoreQty.Text == "")
            {
                drNewdtRow["StoreQty"] = "0";
            }
            else
            {
                drNewdtRow["StoreQty"] = Convert.ToDecimal(txtStoreQty.Text);
            }

            drNewdtRow["ContainerTypeCode"] = ddlContainerType.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim();
            drNewdtRow["ContainerTypeDescription"] = ddlContainerType.SelectedItem.Text.Trim();
            drNewdtRow["ActuallQty"] = Convert.ToDecimal(txtActuallQty.Text);
            drNewdtRow["PcsQty"] = "0";

            //if (ddlItemName.SelectedValue.Substring(4, 1) == "F")
            //    drNewdtRow["PONo"] = "-";
            //else
            //    drNewdtRow["PONo"] = ddlPONo.SelectedItem.Text.Trim();

            if (ddlPurchaseType.SelectedItem.Text == "Credit Purchase")
            {
                if (ddlItemName.SelectedValue.Substring(4, 1) == "F")
                    drNewdtRow["PONo"] = "-";
                else
                    drNewdtRow["PONo"] = ddlPONo.SelectedItem.Text.Trim();
            }
            else
            {
                drNewdtRow["PONo"] = "-";
            }


            //if (ddlItemName.SelectedValue.ToString().Substring(4, 1) == "P")
            //{
            //    drNewdtRow["PcsQty"] = txtPcs.Text;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    drNewdtRow["PcsQty"] = "0";
            //}

            Newdt.Rows.Add(drNewdtRow);

            Griddt = Newdt.Copy();
            if (Session["DtAll"] != null)
            {
                DtAll = (DataTable)(Session["DtAll"]);
            }
            DtAll.Merge(Griddt, true);
            DtAll.AcceptChanges();
            GrdGRn.DataSource = DtAll;
            Session["DtAll"] = DtAll;                        
            GrdGRn.DataBind();
            GrdGRn.Visible = true;
```

Below is the Header I have Included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../javascript/Store/GrnEntry.js" language="javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../javascript/Common/CommonScript.js" language="javascript"></script>
```

Below is the JS file:

```
function fnCheckValidation()
{
    var Item= document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_ddlItem");
    var ItemName=document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_txtItemName");
    var ChallanQty=document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_txtChallanQty");
    var ActuallQty =document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_txtActuallQty");
    var TotChalan=document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTotChallanQty");
    var TotRecvd= document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTotRecvdQty");

if(Item.value=="")
    { 
        alert("Please Select Item!");
        Item.focus();
        return false; 

    }

    if(ChallanQty.value=="")
    {
        alert("Please Enter Challan Qty!");
        return false; 
    }

    if(ActuallQty.value=="")
    {
        alert("Please Enter Actuall Qty!");
        return false; 
    }

    TotChalan.readOnly= true;
    TotRecvd.readOnly= true;


    return true;

}



function fnClearAll()
{
    document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Branch1_txtBranchCode").value="";
    document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Branch1_TxtBranchName").value="";
    document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Branch1_ddlState").value="--Select State--";
    document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Branch1_ddlCity").value="--Select City--";
    document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Branch1_txtFloor").value="";
    document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Branch1_txtRoomNumber").value="";
    document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Branch1_txtPinCode").value="";
    document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Branch1_txtEmailId").value="";
    document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Branch1_txtFax").value="";
    document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Branch1_txtPostOffice").value="";
    document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Branch1_txtPoliceStation").value="";
    document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Branch1_txtMetro").value="";
    document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Branch1_txtRemarks").value="";
    document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Branch1_ddlDivision").value = "--Select Division--";

}

function setMouseClick()
{
    //
    var argv = setMouseClick.arguments;
    var argc = argv.length;

    var Subledger= document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtDescription");
    var Subledgeraccount=document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlAccounts");




    SubMajorHeadNo.value=argv[0];
    SubMajorHeadname.value=argv[1];
    ddlsub.value=argv[2]
    SubMajorHeadNo.readOnly=true;
    return true;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GrdGRn" runat="server" Height="61px" Width="650px" ForeColor="Black" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" CellPadding="2" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="Tan" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="5" OnRowDataBound="GrdGRn_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="GrdGRn_RowCommand"  OnRowDeleting="GrdGRn_RowDeleting">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SrlNo" Visible="False">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SrlNo") %>' ID="LblSrlNo"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="ItemCode" HeaderText="ItemCode"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Name"><EditItemTemplate>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="LblItemName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ItemName") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="ChallanQty" HeaderText="ChallanQty"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="StoreQty" HeaderText="StoreQty"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ContainerTypeCode" Visible="False">
<ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="lblContainerTypeCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ContainerTypeCode") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField><asp:BoundField DataField="ContainerTypeDescription" HeaderText="ContainerTypeDescription"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="ActuallQty" HeaderText="ActuallQty"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="PcsQty" HeaderText="PcsQty"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="PONo" HeaderText="PONo"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete"><ItemTemplate>
<span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to Delete the record?')">
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkB" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ItemName")%>'
 CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete">
</asp:LinkButton>
</span>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
<FooterStyle BackColor="Tan"></FooterStyle><PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" ForeColor="DarkSlateBlue">
</PagerStyle>
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite"></SelectedRowStyle>
<HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod"></AlternatingRowStyle>
</asp:GridView>
```

Can anyone Advice on this please? How to Bind the data from DataTable to Grid Control.

Comment: maybe the problem it's in the aspx page. can you put the grid definition in asp?

Comment: I have Uploaded the grid Definition in asp

Comment: mmm. strange. Maybe try to get the dgv visible=true before DtAll to its datasource

Comment: It is not working... no data is showing at Grid...